# Use pandas to partially unpivot a table

Tags: python, pandas

Here is a table, need to partially unpivot it by class.

```
ID  Class   Type       2017 2018
12A     A   Net         1   7
12B     A   Gross           8
12A     B   Net         3   9
12B     B   Gross       4   10
13A     A   Net         5   11
13C     B   Net         6   5
```

The expected result:

```
ID  Class   Type    2017A       2018A      2017B    2018B
12A    A    Net     1           7           3       9
12B    A    Gross   NaN         8           4       10
13A    A    Net     5           11          NaN     NaN
13C    B    Net     NaN         NaN         6       5
```

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
df1 = df.set_index(['ID','Type','Class']).unstack().sort_index(level=1, axis=1)
df1.columns = ['{}{}'.format(a,b) for a, b in df1.columns]
df1 = df1.reset_index()

s = df.drop_duplicates('ID').set_index('ID')['Class']
df1.insert(1, 'Class', df1['ID'].map(s))
print (df1)
    ID Class   Type  2017A  2018A  2017B  2018B
0  12A     A    Net    1.0    7.0    3.0    9.0
1  12B     A  Gross    NaN    8.0    4.0   10.0
2  13A     A    Net    5.0   11.0    NaN    NaN
3  13C     B    Net    NaN    NaN    6.0    5.0
```

**Explanation**:

1. Reshape by [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) and [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html), sort columns by second levele by [`sort_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html)
2. Flatten `MultiIndex` in columns with list comprehension
3. For column `Class` use [`insert`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.insert.html) for new second column created by [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html)